# Angular $http not reading headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, laravel

I built a small API for my ecommerce application (built in Laravel) so I could use it with a frontend I built in Angular. I put the API on a subdomain and added the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Header to allow calls from the api origin.

The problem is that Angular seems to be stripping out all headers from the request so it never sees my CORS header. My REST API client sees the header correctly. I tried using a basic XMLHttpRequest and it sees the header correctly. But inside Angular, looking at the response from `$http.get()`, I can't see the CORS header, or any other header I've tried.

Here's what my service looks like:

```
angular.module('SFAdmin').factory('Category', function($http){

  $http.defaults.useXDomain = true; 
    var baseUrl = 'http://api.example.com/categories';

    return {
        query: function(){
            return $http.get(baseUrl);
        },
        get: function(id){
            return $http.get(baseUrl + '/' + id);
        },
        create: function(data){
            return $http.post(baseUrl, data);
        },
        update: function(data){
            return $http.put(baseUrl + data.id, data);
        },
        delete: function(id){
            return $http.delete(baseUrl + '/' + id);
        },
        trash: function(){
            return $http.get(baseUrl + '/trash');   
        }
    }
});
```

My Category controller:

```
angular.module('SFAdmin').controller('CategoriesIndexController', function(Category, $scope, $location){

    Category.query().success(function(data){
        $scope.categories = data;
    }).error(function(d, s, h){
      console.log(d, s, h());
    });

});
```

And my api route is sending this:

```
$app->get('/categories/', function(){
            $content = (new App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController())->index();  // index() gets all categories.
            return response($content)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
});
```

How do I get Angular to view incoming headers correctly?